# Find Related Entries with Identical Tags

Tags: entries, search, tags

I'm trying to show related entries for a single item.

I want to look up a specific tag(s), and search for any entries that share the same tag(s) then display those related items.

I've read through the documentation and searched around but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marion's answer is fine but you can also do it a different way, and move the conditional logic out of the for loop. By adding it to the query, you can ask for a specific amount of items to grab, and it won't mess up the loop.index values if you need them.

This is how I would do it.

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).id('not ' ~ currentEntry.id).limit(4).find() %}

{% if relatedEntries | length %}
    {% for e in relatedEntries %}
        {# entry stuff here #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is easier to understand, thanks Sean!

Answer (score 1):

When you have your tag[s], fetch the related entries like this:

```
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries
  .relatedTo({
    targetElement: tag,
    field: 'tags'
  })
%}
```

This is assuming the field for the tag is `tags`, and the tag[s] you want to match is `tag`.

Then you can loop through the related entries. If you want to exclude the current entry, your loop might look like this:

```
{% for e in relatedEntries if e.id != currentEntry.id %}
  do things with {{e}}
{% endfor %}
```